# Row selection dataTable rails - how to get id's list of selected rows

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatable, rows, multipleselection

Hello **I am new to ruby on rails and javascript** and I want to use dataTable in order to select multiple rows in my table. Then I would like to have the list of all the id of the selected rows.

I managed to select multiple rows thanks to the code available on the dataTable website. This is the code :

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selected =[];

  $("#assureur").dataTable({
    
    "rowCallback": function(row,data){
      if($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !==-1){
        $(row).addClass('selected');
      } 
    }
  });

  $('#assureur tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);

    if( index === -1){
      selected.push(id);
    } else {
      selected.splice(index,1);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

});
</script>
```

However I do not understand how to get the list of the rows that I selected.

I searched on the internet but I do not understand how their code work. They talk about using **TableTool** and **fnGetSelected** but I don't know how to use it.

I have read about **alert** but I don't want to show an alert I would rather have an array with all the ids of the selected rows so that I can use this array later.

Then how can I use this array no longer with javascript but with Ruby language ?
I read about using Ajax, or using a hidden field tag and then retrieve the params from the controller....but how does that works ? What do I have to put on my controller to retrieve a variable $var defined in my javascript ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Jquery call:

```
var $yourVar = $("#assureur").find('tbody tr.selected');
```

Comment: Thank you. So in $yourVar I will have all the id of all the rows that I selected. Then I want to show this array in a view. I read that it is possible to pass javascript variable to Ruby only using controller. Can you explain to me how to do it ? Because again I do not understand what is said on the internet it looks rather difficult. They talk about using a hidden field tag that looks the easiest way to handle it ?

Comment: if you need to send a javascript variable to the server, you would have to call a POST to the server containing your variable. For example, submitting a Form tag with the attribute remore=true or using an ajax call. this site here is a good gide for you to start: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Isn't it possible to write a div in my views, with id="selection" and then to write in my script : $('#selection').html($yourVar) ?

Comment: I advise you to do some experimentation with JQuery in separated. You could build a text file with your table and some Javascript code. Then rename it to .html and open it in your Browser. After that you can play with it for a while so you could understand what is inside the $yourVar variable and how to manipulate its information.